# Alphabet to Star shape in C++ programming

Tags: c++

I have a code in C++ programming language, I want to change the entered characters (eg: JACK) into star shape. the program does it well, but the problem is that it prints each char in a new line but I want them to be printed in the same line. 
many thanks in advance for your help

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


void printA(){           // Functions

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) // A
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || j == 0 || j == 4)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printC(){

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)    // C
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}


void printO(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)    // O
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if ((i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || j == 4) && i != j)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printE(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   // E
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || i == 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printF(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)    // F
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printG(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // G
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || i == 2 && j >= 2 || j == 4 && i >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printH(){

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)     // H
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 2 || j == 4 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printI(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)     // I
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printB(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // B
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || j == 4 || i == 2)
            {
                if (i != j){
                    cout << "*";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printL(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // L
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 4 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printD(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   // D
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 || j == 4)
            {
                if (!(i == j))
                    cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printT(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   // T
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || j == 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printU(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // U
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 4 || i == 4 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printY(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   // Y
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 0 && i <= 2 || i == 2 || j == 4)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}


void printJ(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)      // J
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 4 || i == 4 || j == 0 && i >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}


void printN(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // N
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == j || j == 4 || j == 0)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printP(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // P
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || j == 0 || j == 4 && i <= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printR(){

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // R
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 2 || j == 0 || j == 4 && i <= 2 || i == j && i >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printS(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)   // S
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 0 && i <= 2 || i == 2 || j == 4 && i >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printZ(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // Z
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 || i == 4 || j == 4 - i)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printQ(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // Q
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == 0 && j != 4 || i == 3 && j != 4 || j == 0 && i != 4 || j == 3 && i != 4 || i == 4 && j == 4)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}



void printW(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // W
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 0 || j == 4 || j == i && j >= 2 || j == 4 - i && j <= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
void printX(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // x
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == j || j == 4 - i)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
void printV(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // V
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (i == j && j <= 2 || j == 4 - i && j >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
void printM(){
    for (int i = 0; i<7; i++)  // M
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<7; j++)
        {

            if (i == j && i <= 3 || j == 6 - i && i <= 3 || j == 0 || j == 6)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
void printK(){
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)  // K
    {

        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {

            if (j == 0 || j == 4 - i && i <= 2 || i == j && i >= 2)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

        }

        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main(){     // Main Function

    char c[100]={};
    bool b = true;
    int l=1;

        while (b){

        cout << "Enter Alphabat to Print OR Exit Press 0 : ";
        cin >> c;
        l=strlen(c);
            l--;
            for (int i=0; i<=l;i++)
        switch (c[i]){
        if (l<0)
        {
            cout<<l; //<<endl;
        }
        else {
        case 'A':
            printA();
            break;

        case 'B':
            printB();
            break;

        case 'C':
            printC();
            break;

        case 'D':
            printD();
            break;

        case 'E':
            printE();
            break;

        case 'F':
            printF();
            break;

        case 'G':
            printG();
            break;

        case 'H':
            printH();
            break;

        case 'I':
            printI();
            break;

        case 'J':
            printJ();
            break;

        case 'K':
            printK();
            break;

        case 'L':
            printL();
            break;

        case 'M':
            printM();
            break;

        case 'N':
            printN();
            break;

        case 'O':
            printO();
            break;

        case 'P':
            printP();
            break;

        case 'Q':
            printQ();
            break;

        case 'R':
            printR();
            break;

        case 'S':
            printS();
            break;

        case 'T':
            printT();
            break;

        case 'U':
            printU();
            break;

        case 'V':
            printV();
            break;

        case 'W':
            printW();
            break;

        case 'X':
            printX();
            break;

        case 'Y':
            printY();
            break;

        case 'Z':
            printZ();
            break;



        default:

            b = false;

            }
        } // end switch
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really? One function for each letter? Consider using a monochrome bitmap font and translate each bit to a space if 0 or asterisk if 1. Much easier to write, maintain, and modify.

Comment: You're right Colonel Thirty Two, and I mentioned in the title but I did a mistake in text message.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look closer to the `man ascii` command in your terminal, you'll find the character `\r` also known as "carriage ret". This might answer your problematic actually.

By printing it, it brings your display cursor at the beginning of the current line without generating a new line.

Just try

```
cout << '\r';
```

And avoid the

```
cout << endl;
```

which brings a new line with it (Here an explanation of [endl](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/?kw=endl))

Comment: Thanks Souss I tried it but it prints just the last char for example if you enter (JONE) it just prints (E), is the there any solution for this?

Comment: I'ld say that you didn't print this character in the right place into your loops :)

You should print it before doing any other printing (here your you'll print before '\r' and after each letters of JONE)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using a "character by character" approach here is difficult in the console.

One cute and feasible way to accomplish your task in the console by having a list of std::string for each star "character", where every entry in the vector is a vertical slice of the output.

you can define a class to represent partial "star strings" and you can keep appending new star characters to it by appending the appropriate lists.

the best way to accomplish that is to create a class starChars and overload the + operator for appropriate concatenation. (in this case appending the lists one by one). note that you probably want all characters to have the same number of height.(even if you need to leave some empty)

```
class starChars
{
 private std::list<std::string> content; 
...

starChars operator+(starChars & newCharacter)...

}
```

Comment: _"you can't go back to it anymore"_ - You [usually] can with a _backspace_ and you definitely can with native or specialized API's.

Comment: right, but the process would probably be painful for multiple character printing anyway.

Comment: Not painful just a little more effort and a far cry from _"you can't go back to it anymore"_.